# Filter Dependency issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, JS, etc., and would appreciate very much if someone could please assist me with the next issue:

- I was asked to implement several filters and exposed them, so visitors could filter the information/data displayed on the page.
- I was asked to hide or show the subordinate filters depending on the option selected in the main filter. I mean, there is a first dropdown menu with the main categories, and below appears a second dropdown menu with subcategories, which dependents on the option selected previously on the first dropdown menu. For example, if the first dropdown menu shows "- Any -", then the second dropdown menu displayed is the one that shows the entire list of subcategories, but if the first dropdown menu shows a main category, then the second dropdown menu displayed is the one that shows the corresponding subcategories (e.g. if the Army Corps of Engineers main category is selected in the first dropdown menu, then the Army Corps of Engineers subcategories dropdown menu appears below with all its options to select from). I was asked to show all the time the main categories dropdown menu, but just one subcategories dropdown menu corresponding to the option selected in the main categories dropdown menu, and hide the other subcategories dropdown menus. So, just one of the subcategory dropdown menus is showed at a time.
- To achieve this I implemented the next jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

if($("#edit-command").val() == "All"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "1"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "2"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "3"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "4"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "5"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "6"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "7"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 }
 if($("#edit-command").val() == "8"){
 $("#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper").hide();
 $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper").show();
 }

})(jQuery);
```

- So, the jQuery works well as far a showing and hiding the subcategory dropdown menus depending on the option selected on the main categories dropdown menu.
- However, I noticed a problem with the information/data is displayed after the filters render and the page reloads.
- I will try to explain myself as clear as possible, step by step, in the next example:

1) I go to the page, both the main categories (Command) and the subcategories (Contracting Offices) dropdown menus show "- Any -", and all the information/data is shown

2) I click on the Command dropdown menu, select Army Corps of Engineers, the Contracting Offices dropdown menu changes to ACE Contracting Offices, and the information/data displayed changes accordingly

3) I click on the Command dropdown menu, select another command, for example Army Materiel Command, the Contracting Offices dropdown menu changes to AMC Contracting Offices, and the information/data displayed changes accordingly. Again, I click on the Command dropdown menu, select another command, for example National Guard Bureau, the Contracting Offices dropdown menu changes to NGB Contracting Offices, and the information/data displayed changes accordingly. So far everything works well.

4) However, the problem happens when I select an option from Command and also an option from the Contracting Offices dropdown menu.

5) Let me give you next several examples.

6) I select Army Corps of Engineers under Command, then I select Army Geospatial Center under ACE Contracting Offices, the information/data at the bottom changes accordingly and everything works and looks well.

7) Now, when I select, for example, "- Any -" under Command, the ACE Contracting Offices dropdown menu changes to Contracting Office Name, but the information displayed keeps showing the Army Geospatial Center data from the previous selection.

8) Now, if I select again Army Corps of Engineers under Command, the Contracting Office Name dropdown menu changes to ACE Contracting Offices, but Army Geospatial Center remains selected, and the information displayed keeps showing the Army Geospatial Center data.

9) Now, if I select again "- Any -" under Command, the ACE Contracting Offices dropdown menu changes to Contracting Office Name, but the information displayed still shows the Army Geospatial Center data.

10) Now, if I change the Command back to Army Corps of Engineering, the Contracting Office Name dropdown menu changes back to ACE Contracting Offices, but Army Geospatial Center remains selected in the subcategory dropdown menu, and the information at the bottom still displays the Army Geospatial Center data.

11) Now, say I select Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory under ACE Contracting Offices subcategory dropdown menu, the information/data displayed changes accordingly, and everything seems to look and work well.

12) Now, if I select again "- Any -" under Command, the ACE Contracting Offices dropdown menu changes to Contracting Office Name, but the information displayed again doesn't render appropriately, as the Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory data keep being displayed, just like in the previous example with Army Geospatial Center.

13) Now, if I select another Command, for example Army Materiel Command, the Contracting Office Name dropdown menu changes for AMC Contracting Offices, but the information/data displayed disappears completely, and if I change the contracting office, the problems remains, same thing if I change the command, the data still doesn't show.

Please click on the next links to see screenshots for visual reference:

[image1](http://sellingtoarmy.com/sites/default/files/filter_dependency_issue_1.jpg)
[image2](http://sellingtoarmy.com/sites/default/files/filter_dependency_issue_2.jpg)

What do I need to add to my jQuery code, so the filters work as needed and the data is displayed correctly?

In advance, thank you very much for your kind attention and prompt assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

There is too much going on in your description for anyone to easily understand the issue. This is why it really helps to try to reduce the problem down to a short, simple, self-contained test case. It's even better if you can also create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem.

I would like to share a programming lesson though. There is a lot of duplicate code in your example. This makes it hard to follow and maintain the code, and easy for unintentional errors to be introduced.

Since all the duplicate code blocks do the same thing, the only difference being which selectors are hidden or shown, you can combine all of this code into one function with only a single list of selectors. For example, you could do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ( $ ) {
    updateVisibility();

    var selectors = [
        '#edit-contracting-office-id-wrapper',
        '#edit-ace-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-inscom-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-amc-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-medcom-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-mraa-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-smdc-contracting-offices-wrapper',
        '#edit-ngb-contracting-offices-wrapper'
    ];

    function updateVisibility() {
        var value = $('#edit-command').val();
        if( value == 'All' ) {
            value = 0;  // 'All' refers to the first selector
        }
        value = +value;  // Convert to a number
        // Hide each element, but show the one where index == value
        $.each( selectors, function( index, selector ) {
            $(selector).toggle( index == value );
        });
    }
});
```

This code loops through all your selectors, hiding all of the elements except for the one that you want to show based on the value of the `#edit-command` element.

Also there is an error in the way you used jQuery's `ready` function:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
    // ...
})( jQuery );
```

It should be called like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
    // ...
});
```

It's also very important to use proper indentation, as shown in these examples. It makes the code much easier to follow.

Comment: Michael, thanks so much! I am so sorry my description of the problem is so long and I am not that clear enough. In brief, I guess my problem is that, even though the main category filter is changed, a previously selected subcategory filter (child) remains selected and its data displayed. So, would it be just a matter of "deselecting" the child dropdowns when the parent dropdown changes?

Comment: For instance: 

$("#edit-contracting-office-id").val('All');

should set the selection in the Contracting Office ID dropdown to -Any-.

So, would I have to implement the change event on the "Command" dropdown (parent) and just unselect all options in the "child" dropdowns?

Comment: something like this:

$("#edit-command").on('change', function(evt) {
   $("#edit-contracting-office-id").val('All');
   $("#edit-ace-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-inscom-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-amc-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-medcom-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-mraa-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-peo-stri-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-smdc-contracting-offices").val('All');
   $("#edit-ngb-contracting-offices").val('All');
});

Comment: No apology needed! Re your last comment, instead of repeating the `$(...).val('All');` nine times, since we have the `selectors` array you can simply use: `$( selectors.join() ).val('All');` to select and change all of them at once.

Comment: Michael, thanks again for your comprehension and kind support! So, where in your code, the one you wrote combining the function and the single list of selectors, would you add that new piece of code you just mentioned? I mean, how would the final code, including everything, be? Thanks!!

Comment: Glad my notes are helpful! In that last bit of code, it would go inside the `.on()` function you wrote in the previous comment, like this: `$("#edit-command").on('change', function() { $( selectors.join() ).val('All'); });`. And this entire statement would go somewhere inside the main `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });` block.

Comment: Michael, once again, thank you!! I'll give it a try.